# dnspython: How can I get response as bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, dns, dnspython

What I am trying to do is make a dns query using the `dnspython` library and get the response in the dns wire format or a string of bytes. Right not the `dns.resolver.resolve()` method is returning a `<class 'dns.resolver.Answer'>`

Is there a way I can get the dns response in the wire format or convert my `dns.resolver.Answer` type to wire format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the message to the compressed DNS wire format by using something like

```
my_answer.response.to_wire()
```

if that's what you need.

From the [docs](https://dnspython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/resolver-class.html?highlight=Answer#dns.resolver.Answer.response):

> `response`:     A `dns.message.Message`, the response message.

and [also](https://dnspython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/message-class.html#dns.message.Message.to_wire):

> `to_wire(origin=None, max_size=0, multi=False, tsig_ctx=None, **kw)`
>
> Return a string containing the message in DNS compressed wire format.